# Java int[] comparator

Tags: java

Trying to write a custom comparator for int[] as follows:

```
public class arrayComparator implements Comparator<int[]>{
    @Override
    public int compare(int[] a, int[] b){
        return a[1] - b[1];
    }
}
```

But this is not correct for the case where `a = [-2147483646,-2147483645],[2147483646,2147483647]`, `b = [-2147483646,-2147483645],[2147483646,2147483647]`. How should I revise my code?

Comment: Do you want to compare between [] and [] or [][] and [][] ?

Comment: And what does it mean for an array to be greater- or less-than another? What if they're different sizes?

Comment: integer overflow when you calculate the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Precisely to avoid that kind of problems with [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), to compare `int` values with natural order we should ***always*** use built-in [`Integer.compare(int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,int)).

So change

```
return a[1] - b[1];
```

into

```
return  Integer.compare(a[1], b[1]);
```

BTW since `Comparator` is *functional interface* we can provide its implementation via lambdas and/or method-references:

```
Comparator<int[]> arrayComparator1 = (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a[1], b[1]);
Comparator<int[]> arrayComparator2 = Comparator.comparingInt(arr -> arr[1]);
```

---

Aside from main question, generally accepted coding style for Java is that names of non-primitive-types should start with uppercase like `String` `ArrayList`. So change `arrayComparator` into `ArrayComparator`.

Comment: which is, for common knowledge purpose, based on : `public static int compare(int x, int y) {  return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1); }`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're learning about this, here are several ways of doing it.

```
public arrayComparator implements Comparator<int[]>{
    @Override
    public int compare(int[] a, int[] b){
        return a[1] > b[1] ? 1 : a[1] < b[1] ? -1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Or

```
public arrayComparator implements Comparator<int[]>{
    @Override
    public int compare(int[] a, int[] b){
        
         if (a[1] > b[1]) {
              return 1;
         }
         if (a[1] < b[1]) {
             return -1;
         }
         return 0;
    }
}
```

Or

```
public arrayComparator implements Comparator<int[]>{
    @Override
    public int compare(int[] a, int[] b){
        return Integer.compare(a[1], b[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler:

```
Comparator<int[]> intArrayComparator = (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a[1], b[1]);
```

For example, to be used as:

```
int[][] arr = ....;
Arrays.sort(arr, intArrayComparator);
```

There's no need to make an explicitly named custom class for this.